# Access directly a column inside an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d

I am trying to access not a single element inside a 2D ArrayList but an entire column. Since it is very easy to do that when you need a row (since the 2D Array is read by row and columns), it was not so trivial to me to do the same for a column.

Do you have any suggestion relevant to that?

Any kind of help will be very appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: `array[1][x]` can be scanned with `x` to access the first row, and `array[x][1]` can be used to scan the first column.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do that without transforming the ArrayList in a Vector and through a double cycle "for" over the row index (as variable to get all the column) and over the column index that should change at the end of the iteration over all the rows. I don't know if I was clear enough... Thank you Tim!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly access a column in a 2-D row-oriented list. You can, however, always extract the required value.

To retrieve, column at index `n`, you can simply run:

```
twoDList.stream().map(innerList -> innerList.get(n))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This can also be easily changed to a normal for-each loop.

```
List<T> column = new ArrayList<T>();

for(List<T> row: twoDList) {
    column.add(row.get(n));
}
```

Comment: It was exactly what I suspected... no possibility to access directly a column at index n. Many thanks, Ernest! I have used your 2nd solution and it works perfeclty to me!!! Many thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `List` within a `List`:

```
List<List<String>> listWithList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

To get the *child* `List` from the *parent* `List` you need to call for example `0` for the first *child* `List`:

```
List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>();
anotherList = listWithList.get(0); // get the first complete List
```

To get a `String` from the *child* `List` you need to call:

```
String someText = anotherList.get(0); // get the first String
```

or directly from the `List` within the `List`:

```
String moreText = listWithList.get(0).get(0); // get the first String from the first List
```

Comment: Many thanks, David. It was exactly what I did, but I needed a way to access in some way an entire column, while using the method listWithList.get(0).get(0) gave me the possibility to access a single element of the 2D ArrayList. Many thanks for your detailed example!

Answer (score 0):

I posted something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49368487/823393) recently.

Here I create a `ColumnList` object that allows me to manipulate a single column of a 2D array. In this case I am sorting it.

```
class ColumnList<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final T[][] array;
    private final int column;

    public ColumnList(T[][] array, int column) {
        this.array = array;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return array[index][column];
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        return array[index][column] = element;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] array = {
            {6, 8, 9, 16},
            {0, 6, -3, 4},
            {18, 2, 1, 11}
    };
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
    // Sort each column separately.
    for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
        List<Integer> column = new ColumnList<>(array, i);
        Collections.sort(column);
    }
    System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```